# Bootstrap Collapse menu not going vertical

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue with the default behaviour for a bootstrap menu which I am hoping someone has a solution for.
At the moment I can see that bootstrap is working fine and the menu looks fine when the bowser window is large and all the items are shown horizontally which is what I want and would expect.

However when the menu collapses I would expect the items to be listed vertically as supposed to horizontally which is what I am getting at the moment.

Using the below post I can see that there is some JavaScript being used to change the items to list vertically however when I use it. The items stay vertical regardless of the browser window size.

[responsive-menu-twitter-bootstrap-asp-net](http://techbrij.com/responsive-menu-twitter-bootstrap-asp-net)

Is there a solution or work around for this?

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-header">
   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   </button>
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Name</a>
  </div>
  <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">   
   <asp:Menu ID="mainMenu" 
    CssClass="navbar navbar-fixed-right"
    StaticMenuStyle-CssClass="nav nav-tabs"
    StaticSelectedStyle-CssClass="active"
    DynamicMenuStyle-CssClass="dropdown-menu"
    RenderingMode="List"
    DataSourceID="mainnavSitemap"
    Orientation="Horizontal"
    runat="server" 
    StaticDisplayLevels="2"
    MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="0" 
    StaticSubMenuIndent="0" />
  </div>   
 </div>
</nav>
```

Thank You

Comment: create a fiddle and reproduce the issue. and post the rendered  html, not asp markup..

Answer (score 0):

Navbar menu items are an unordered list `ul>li`. The default for a list is vertical. Bootstrap has the following css to make the menu horizontal in desktops,

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.navbar-nav>li {
    float: left;
}
```

Check for another class which you have added onto your list items which is overriding the default vertical style on mobile resolutions